# Correctly assigning memory and do I still need to allocate memory?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I currently have the following two structs:

```
typpedef struct data1 {
    int var1;
    data2_t *var2;
    ...
}
```

And:

```
typedef struct data2 {
    int var1;
    ...
} data2_t;
```

Right now, I'm trying to compare `int x` with a value in `data2_t **dataArray`, and if the value is found in the array, `memAddress` is set to point to where the value is in memory:

```
int main(...) {
    
    data2_t **arrayVar, *memAddress;

    ....

    if(inArray(valToCompare, arrayVar, arraySize, &memAddres) {
        ...
    }

    ....

    return 0;
}

int inArray(int x, data2_t **dataArray, int size, data2_t **memAddress) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(val == dataArray[i]->var1) {
            // Variable is in array
            *memAddress = dataArray[i];
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

First of all, is `memAddress` pointing to the desired memory space once out of the function?

Secondly, if I was to then do this:

```
int main(...) {
    
    data2_t **arrayVar, *memAddress;
    data1_t **dataSet;

    ....

    if(inArray(valToCompare, arrayVar, arraySize, &memAddress) == 1) {
        dataSet[index]->var2 = memAddress;
    }

    ....

    return 0;
}
```

Will `var2` in the `data1_t struct` be set to point at the previously matched data, and would I still need to allocate memory for `var2` if memory has already been allocated to the memory in question?

Thanks

Comment: In case `arrayVar` is a 1D array, then using `data2_t**` doesn't make sense. In case `arrayVar` is a 2D array, then the function `inArray` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to allocate memory for the field *var2* in this case. The only things to look out for is assigning addresses of local variables (which go out of scope) or using a pointer to a variable which has been freed. A good practice is to only use the address-of operator for actual parameters like you do in your code to simulate call by reference. If you have complicated pointer logic in your program it may be worth using a garbage collector library like [Boehm GC](https://www.hboehm.info/gc/). The garbage collector will prevent "use after free" and memory leaks by automatically freeing allocated memory when there are no pointers to it.